# get object values by other object key

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects

**object1 value**

```
 {
"type_Id": 10,
"type_Name": "Admission Fee-One Time (1)",
"old Admission": "500.00",
"new Admission": "1000.00",
"staff Fee": "200.00", 
"free Education": "50.00"
 }
```

**object2 value**

```
{ 
"fee_category_Id": 2,
"fee_category_Name": "Old Admission", 
"fee_Descripition": "Admission FEE"
}
```

object1 key names are dynamic and could vary.

I want to get the value from **object1** by **object2** key name

I tried to do this but it is not working
my attempt

```
   Object.keys(this.object1).forEach((key) => {
   Object.keys(this.object2).forEach((keys) => { 
  if(this.object1[key][this.object2[keys].fee_category_Name]){///but it never true

 //get the fee amount
 }
 });
});
```

What I am missing in this.

Comment: _"Is there any issue with the above approach"_ - Obviously, or why else would you ask this question? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Thanx @Andres for highlighting the key points, I will improve my future posts by following these points. However I already specify where it is not working.

Comment: "where" is only one part of a good question. What is `his.object1[key][this.object2[keys].fee_category_Name]` supposed to do? What does it instead? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own (debugging)? `key` is the name of a property in `object1`. `object1[key]` is the value of that property. Why do you expect `<value>[<key of object2>]` to return anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, get keys from object2 and check for their existence in object1.

```
Object.keys(object2).forEach((key) => {
  if(object1.hasOwnProperty(object2[key])) {
    const value = object1[object2[key]];
    // do whatever you like with 'value'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thnx!! I tried this but didn't work. if(object1.hasOwnProperty(key)) { } always return false.

Comment: this.datas[x.fee_category_Name] returning undefined. but If I write this.datas["old Admission"] than it returning amount

Comment: @VirenderThakur updated the answer, can you check now?

Comment: @KanishAnand please see the runtime response and what I am talking about regarding the issue.     https://ibb.co/8XY1KYc

Comment: @VirenderThakur I updated the answer and it works now. I tested with the following : 
`data = { "old Admission" : 500 }` as `object` and `xs = { fee_categpry_name: 'old Admission' }` as `object2` . Did you try with the updated code above?

Comment: yes I tried but it still not returning true it exit the if(object1.hasOwnProperty(object2[key])) {} condition. Please see debugging in console https://ibb.co/WsDz7Tw

Comment: Here is the full json copy I am working with.  https://jsonblob.com/922544692961492992
http://jsonblob.com/922547072968966144